# Import Postgresql to phpmyadmin

Tags: postgresql, phpmyadmin

I want to change my database to ***phpmyadmin*** from ***PostgreSQL***. I got a backup from PostgreSQL but I don't know how to import ***.backup*** file to phpmyadmin. When I import file, some errors show about pgadmin config that phpmyadmin don't know. Can you help me?
For example, I have this line in ***.backup*** file :

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
SET default_tablespace = '';
SET default_with_oids = false;
```

insert sqls is like this line :

```
COPY users (id, password, type, customer, shop) FROM stdin;
1049    $2a$10$1l6qdCkJYOESSDCYcOKS5urRRud/zQqFIpFbcRAOgmIjMcwICPHbK    0   300 \N
```

this is not defined in phpmyadmin and every insert SQL in the pgadmin file is like the top line...

Comment: This doesn't work this way, in order to get help, provide us wide spectrum of details, for instance, your error log.

Comment: @RonS Ok lets check again

Answer (score 0):

[Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) is the perfect solution for painless migration, column to column mapping, character encoding and also opensource.

Or you can use [pg2mysql](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php)

I hope this helps you